# Is there a way to open an Access form with parameters by link?

Tags: ms-access

I have an access form and I'd like to give a hyperlink to it with an ID parameter, is that possible?
I need the access equivilent of something like `https://www.example.com/something?parameter=value`, but instead have it like `file://something/something/myform.accdb?parameter=value`

this **has** to be by link.

Comment: Here is a solution that comes close if your app is installed in a fixed path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67994135/3820271

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't execute a file (calling msaccess.exe to open the database) this way.

Your link will ask the browser to *download* the file as an accdb file is of a format that cannot be displayed in the browser.

However, you can create a *shortcut* to the form:

- Open Access
- Go to the navigation pane
- Drag and drop the form to open to the Desktop
- Close Access

Now, double-click the shortcut, and it will open Access and, right away, then the form.

Comment: can I add a parameter to this? as in, a parameter for the form

Comment: Not that I know of. You would probably have to write the parameter to a (temp) file, then modify the form to read that file when opening, and behave accordingly.