# ms-access:// URI Protocol Gives an "Unsafe Content" Error

Tags: ms-access, office365, uri

I'm trying to set up our intranet site, so with a click of a button, it opens MS Access Database file in MS Access app.

The file (one of many we want to access this way) is located on a shared drive mapped onto our machines as S:.

I've done some reading and it looks like I need to use `ms-access://` URI Protocol. I have created the set of the followig links:

`ms-access://shareName/path/to/the/file/MSAccessDB.accdb`

`ms-access://S:/path/to/the/file/MSAccessDB.accdb`

`ms-access:///S:/path/to/the/file/MSAccessDB.accdb` - (3 x / to indicate it is a local file)

`ms-access://our.domain.local/S:/path/to/the/file/MSAccessDB.accdb`

`ms-access://our.domain.local/shareName/path/to/the/file/MSAccessDB.accdb`

In all cases, I have the same outcome - an error message saying this

[image: Error Message]

I have added the website to "Local Intranet" or to the "Trusted Sites" on the "Internet Properties". I have also added the file location to MS Office Trusted Locations; however, the problem still exists.

I have spent significant time with Google and ChatGPT and neither of them gave me any sensible solution.

I would appreciate any help you guys can offer. And if you have any suggestion on how to do it differntly, I'm more than happy to hear them out.

Just wanted to mention that the page is static and, even though, we can use JS on it, we do not intend to use any server side code like .Net or PHP.

Thanks

Comment: Does this help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1186215/security-warning-when-opening-document-with-uri-sc

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. This relates to a warning message, which you can pass with a confirmation button. My message is an error, which stops me from going further. I tried the solution, but no lusk there. Thanks anyway @June7

Comment: Somewhat related, but for Email: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67993711/how-to-send-html-attachment-including-hyperlink-in-email-body-with-outlook -- maybe a custom URL protocol can help here too.